# Couldn't find CycleRoad with id=1 (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CycleRoadsController#destroy 

Couldn't find CycleRoad with id=1
```

Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
class CycleRoadsController < ApplicationController

   before_action :set_cycle_road, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @cycle_roads = CycleRoad.all
  end

  def new
        @cycle_road = CycleRoad.new
      end

def destroy
    @cycle_road.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cycle_roads_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_cycle_road
      @cycle_road = CycleRoad.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cycle_road_params
      params.require(:cycle_road).permit(:name, :begin, :finish, :km, :descriptionm)
    end
end
```

Comment: show us `set_cycle_road` and `destroy` methods?

Comment: It seems you try to destroy `CycleRoad` record that doesn't exist in DB.

Comment: sorry, i though i show that. Now is is

Comment: Do you have a `cycle_road record` with `id = 1`? It seems there is no `record` with `id = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`before_filter` method `set_cycle_road` is there for `destroy` action which finds the `cycle_road`, if cycle road for some id passed in params doesn't exist `find` will throw an error. You can handle this using `where` instead.

```
def set_cycle_road
  @cycle_road = CycleRoad.where("id = ?", params[:id]).first
  if @cycle_road.blank?
    flash[:notice] = "Cycle road not found"
    redirect_to #your_path
  end
end
```

Comment: You could simplify the query a bit: `CycleRoad.where(id: params[:id]).first`

Comment: Or `CycleRoad.find_by_id(params[:id])`.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem of why you are trying to destroy a CycleRoad that doesn't exist in the first place...

Comment: If it's not present, user will be redirected to another page, what's wrong with this?

Comment: because you have a page displaying a link that will never work. You can't hit a destroy action by just typing a URL in your browser - it's coming from a direct action within the Rails app. Fix the cause of the problem - the invalid link.

Comment: The error was coming because record with id=1 doesn't exist in the database, I've just handled the error. Before filter method has been applied on destroy action to fetch the record, if the record is not present user will be redirected to a path with error message. Its upto the coder what path he wants user to be redirected to.

Answer (score 2):

This error is occurring when ActiveRecord is trying to find record with id you have passed and could not find it.

The error may occur because of;

1. If you have intentionally deleted the records through rails console.
2. Your params[:id] is overridden by any method (may be your set_cycle_road method).

   Use rails logging to inspect the params[:id] in the "delete" method and try to correct the code.